# In Ubuntu 23.04, the order of screens in a dual monitor setup isn't saved after a reboot or re-login

Tags: multiple-monitors, wayland, 23.04

I'm facing an issue with my Ubuntu 23.04 setup on a notebook. Every time I reboot, re-login, put the notebook to sleep, or even disconnect the HDMI cable, the order of screens in my dual monitor setup isn't retained. Additionally, the selection preferences, whether it's set to "external only" or "join screens," are not saved either.

Here are the specifics of my setup:

- Wayland
- Intel Iris Graphics
- Linux 6.2.0-34-generic
- GNOME 44.3
- Connected via HDMI

It's a fresh install, and I've ensured everything is updated.